# Replace block with variable containing multiple lines containing special characters

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file out.txt

```
test1 {
       car "ok"
       disk "N/A"
       tire 4
}
```

And I need to replace the whole block `/test1 {/ , /\}/`  with another block that should be in variable ( bash)

So in the script it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="
    test1 {
           car "fail"
           disk "2"
           tire 1
    }
"
sed -r --follow-symlinks -e "/^test1 /,/\}/c\\${text}" out.conf
```

Which of course does not work since sed process the variable with { and new lines like its sed parameter ... but how to go around it ?

Comment: Is there a reason you use *almost* valid JSON? Switching to a standard format would probably make more sense.

Comment: @tripleee Oh man if I could use valid Json that would make my life 100% easier, sadly as you say its "almost valid" json.. so I have to come up with so much wired stuff to automate things, its not even funny. This is just a small example, close to what I have to make it easier to solve. And I can't change the format :-/

Comment: @VladoPortos: Do you want a sed only solution or fine with better suited toold like awk/perl?

Comment: @anubhava preferably sed but from what I have seen there is no easy solution for this, so if awk can make it easy I'll use that :)

Comment: Can your replacement block contain `}` or `\t` (or other escaped character) inside the double quoted strings or anywhere else? Are the `test1 {` and `}` delimiters in your input file always on their own lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `sed`, it is easier doing this with `awk` due to multiline replace and substitution of the text. You may use this `awk`:

```
var="
    test1 {
           car "fail"
           disk "2"
           tire 1
    }
"
awk -v var="$var" 'p && /^[[:blank:]]*}[[:blank:]]*$/ { $0=var; p=0 } 
/^[[:blank:]]*test1[[:blank:]]*\{/ { p=1 } !p' out.conf
```

This awk works as follows:

- Searches for text `test1 {` in a line and set a flag `p=1`
- Continues reading file while `p==1` without printing anything
- if `p==1` and finds a line with `}` then sets `$0` with multiline text passed in variable `var` and resets `p=0`
- Prints line only when `p==0`

Comment: thanks works like charm, not sed as asked in original question but sed solution is just way more complicated.. I accept this as answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. You may please remove `sed` from title of your question :)

Comment: would it be possible to somehow much also inside already matched block of { } 

For example I have:
`main { 
 sub1 {
  car "one"
  tire 2
 }
 
 sub2 {
  car "two"
  tire 4
 }

 sub3 { 
  car "three"
  tire 6
 }
}`

And I match the "main {  and than want to replace sub2 { block...

Comment: It gets really complicated when we have nested brackets and escaped ones. It might be possible but will be tricky

Comment: Welcome to my world :D hahaha I know its a pain

Comment: @VladoPortos you can always ask a followup question. It may not be as difficult as you think depending on the details that you can't fully provide in a comment but can in a question.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I think I have already solved it, kind of backward solution but seems to work... I'm testing it now :)